# How to find the function relating random variable X & Y when only the distributions are known?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

X & Y are a continuous r.v. with the following distributions:

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-x} & x>0 \\ 0 & x <0\end{cases}\tag{pdf}$$

$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}1-e^{-x} & x > 0 \\ 0 & x <0 \end{cases}\tag{cdf}$$

$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} & 0<y<1 \\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{pdf}$$

$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases}\sqrt{y}&0<y<1\\ 0 & otherwise \end{cases}\tag{cdf}$

**How to find the function Y = g(X), given only the distributions for X and Y?**

---

They are claiming the answer is:

$$Y = (1 - e^{-X})^2$$

Comment: The capital $X$ you have there is the r.v? If so try to use the change of variable Theorem which is $$f_{W}(w)=f_{X}(g^{-1}_1(w))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(w)|$$

Comment: yes, both X and Y are r.v.'s

Comment: I don't think change of value theorem works because that only gives you another pdf and I already have every pdf for r.v.'s X and Y.  I'm looking for the function g(X), as in Y= g(X).

Answer (score 5):

One method of solution relies on the fact that the random variable $$U = F_X(X)$$ has a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.  This is because $$\Pr[U \le u] = \Pr[F_X(X) \le u] = \Pr[X \le F_X^{-1}(u)] = F_X(F_X^{-1}(u)) = u$$ for $0 < u < 1$.  This holds whenever $F$ is continuous, thus is invertible.

Consequently, if we know that in this case $$U = F_X(X) = 1 - e^{-X} \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1),$$ and similarly, $$W = F_Y(Y) = \sqrt{Y} \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1),$$ then a suitable transformation taking $X$ to $Y$ is $$Y = F^{-1}_Y(F_X(X)) = (1 - e^{-X})^2.$$

Comment: Thanks.  I can follow your explanation about creating r.v.'s U and W using cdf of X and Y, but where does $Y=F^{-1}_Y\Big(F_X(x)\Big)$ come from?

Comment: I think because, $U=\text{uniform}(0,1)$, and $W=\text{uniform}(0,1)$, therefore, $U=W \longrightarrow F_Y(Y) = F_X(X) \longrightarrow Y = F_Y^{-1}(F_X(X))$

Comment: @pico that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The capital $X$ you have there is the r.v? If so try to use the change of variable Theorem which is $$f_{W}(w)=f_{X}(g^{-1}_1(w))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(w)|$$

EDIT

Heropup already gave the answer